# WinSCP code 4 error when closing file after upload

Tags: file-upload, scripting, command, winscp

Hi coders and codettes (?) I am having some trouble with my WINSCP commands...hoping you can assist.

I have a powershell script that calls WinSCP command line...

```
$LastFile = "$A\BC0722.txt"

& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com' /command "option batch abort" "option confirm off" "open sftp:BankOfTulsa/" "put $LastFile /incoming/temp"
```

This part works fine. It calls up WinSCP no problem...

```
Using username "usern".
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Reading remote directory...
Session started.
Active session: [1] BankOfTulsa
G:\FTP\A\ADropoff\BC0722.TXT |          2 KiB |    0.0 KiB/s | binary | 100%
Cannot close remote file 'temp'.
General failure (server should provide error description).
Error code: 4
Error message from server: Mailbox /clients/usern/pub/incoming/temp exists.
(A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip, Ski(p) all: Abort
```

As you can see I get an error as the above... it doesn't load the file but up until cannot close remote file temp, it looks good...points to note...

```
Cannot close remote file 'temp'.
    General failure (server should provide error description).
    Error code: 4
    Error message from server: Mailbox /clients/usern/pub/incoming/temp exists.
```

I'm not too familiar with WinSCP errors, I did some research but nothing really rang a bell, anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `/incoming/temp` is a directory, you are missing a trailing slash. You should use:

```
put $LastFile /incoming/temp/
```

When you use just the `/incoming/temp`, it means that you want to upload the file to the directory `/incoming` and save it to the file `temp`. What obviously conflicts with an existing subdirectory of the same name.

Quoting the documentation for the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put):

> The last parameter specifies target remote directory and optionally operation mask to store file(s) under different name. *Target directory must end with slash.*

Normally the upload should fail right, when opening/creating the file `temp`. But your server seems to detect the conflict only, when closing the file.